# Understanding javascript event handling and ajax requests

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, highcharts

I tried to learn javascript by trying out examples but gave up, because I couldn't understand the idea of event handling and callbacks.

Here is the problem I am trying to solve.
1. I have a chart (highcharts.js)
2. I am expecting data from the server
3. Javascript will make a request to the server for data points
4. The data has to be appended to the chart

How can I accomplish this? Do you have any book or article that you can recommend? My confusion is mainly, how the callback can update the global objects and in turn cause the elemetns to refresh?

Comment: try reading this for an overview on DOM events http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2013/11/12/an-introduction-to-dom-events/

Comment: http://learn.jquery.com/ajax/ *"My confusion is mainly, how the callback can update the global objects and in turn cause the elemetns to refresh?"* Well, you just put the logic inside the callback. A callback is nothing else than a normal function. But instead of you calling it *explicitly*, some other part of the applications calls it whenever it sees fit (e.g. when the response of an Ajax request was received).

Answer (score 1):

With **jQuery** you can use the call $.get() to get de data from the server. I don't know if you are using an API or just a csv file, so the call with csv could be like this:

```
$.get('/url/to/file.csv', function (data) {
    $('#container').highcharts({
        data: {
            csv: data
        },
        title : "Some title",
        // etc.
});
```

I don't know if is the thing that you are asking for. I leave a [link to ajax example](http://www.highcharts.com/demo/line-ajax) that could help you.

Answer (score 1):

1. Included highcharts.js and required js files in your html/jsp/php pages
2. Server should return xml or JSON data (that needs to be shown in highcharts) to client on request. Here, Response Headers matters.

   ```
    application/json
    text/xml
   ```
3. Using jQuery's $.ajax() function get data(XML or JSON format) from server to assign following values in highcharts

   ```
    xAxis: {
           categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun',
               'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']
       }


    series: [{
           name: 'Tokyo',
           data: [7.0, 6.9, 9.5, 14.5, 18.2, 21.5, 25.2, 26.5, 23.3, 18.3, 13.9, 9.6]
       }, {
           name: 'New York',
           data: [-0.2, 0.8, 5.7, 11.3, 17.0, 22.0, 24.8, 24.1, 20.1, 14.1, 8.6, 2.5]
       }, {
           name: 'Berlin',
           data: [-0.9, 0.6, 3.5, 8.4, 13.5, 17.0, 18.6, 17.9, 14.3, 9.0, 3.9, 1.0]
       }, {
           name: 'London',
           data: [3.9, 4.2, 5.7, 8.5, 11.9, 15.2, 17.0, 16.6, 14.2, 10.3, 6.6, 4.8]
       }]
   ```
4. bind highcharts to a div container on page load / any other event

   ```
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#container').highcharts({
            ....
        });
    });
   ```

   make sure web page has  container

   ```
   <div id="container" style="min-width: 310px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>
   ```

Thats all

Comment: How can I add containers dynamically?

Comment: You can do that with the **.append()** method. What kind of variable decide the number of containers? Do you read it from the database? Assuming you know this variable it could be something like that:

`var num_containers = 5;`
`for (var i = 0; i < num_containers; i++){`
`var html = '<div id="container_'+i+'" class="container" style="min-width: 310px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>';`
`$("#list_containers").append(html);`
`}`'

Comment: jquery's append() method helps you dynamically adding any element. .attr() method helps you to set/unset attributes to any element. Once you add div element to web page, you may again set highcharts binding to the same later.